# Fetching data from PostgreSQL table using SQL Alchemy ORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, backend, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my table model:

```
class EventMediaFile(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = config["eventmediatableName"]
    EventID = db.Column(
        db.String(120),
        primary_key=True
    )
    CameraID = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    Type = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
    URL = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    Width = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    Height = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    MIMEType = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    Filesize = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    Duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    FrameCount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    Codec = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    Extension = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    OriginalFilename = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    Status = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    LastUpdatedDT = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=False), nullable=False)
    GroupID = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    DeviceID = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    RetryCount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    LastEncounteredError = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    ErrorLog = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)

    db.UniqueConstraint(EventID, CameraID, Type)

    def __init__(
        self,
        eventID,
        cameraID,
        type,
        url,
        width,
        height,
        mimeType,
        fileSize,
        duration,
        frameCount,
        codec,
        extension,
        originalFilename,
        status,
        lastUpdatedDT,
        groupID,
        deviceID,
        retryCount,
        lastEncounteredError,
        errorLog
    ):
        self.EventID = eventID
        self.CameraID = cameraID
        self.Type = type
        self.URL = url
        self.Width = width
        self.Height = height
        self.MIMEType = mimeType
        self.Filesize = fileSize
        self.Duration = duration
        self.FrameCount = frameCount
        self.Codec = codec
        self.Extension = extension
        self.OriginalFilename = originalFilename
        self.Status = status
        self.LastUpdatedDT = lastUpdatedDT
        self.GroupID = groupID
        self.DeviceID = deviceID
        self.RetryCount = retryCount
        self.LastEncounteredError = lastEncounteredError
        self.ErrorLog = errorLog
```

This is how I am initializing the **app** and **db**:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And finally i have my function to get all rows based on some condition:

```
def get_downloadable_files_from_EM(app, db):
    with app.app_context():
        stmt = select(EventMediaFile).where(
            or_(EventMediaFile.Status == 'Missing', EventMediaFile.Status == 'Failed')).where(
            EventMediaFile.RetryCount < 3)
        result = db.session.execute(stmt)
        return result.fetchall()
```

- The problem here is I am only getting the primary key value and not all the columns  using the above query:

```
<EventMediaFile event123, camid1, Image>
```

**NOTE:-**
I have also tried the below mentioned query to fetch data from postgresql table:

```
 - result = db.session.query(EventMediaFile).where(
            or_(EventMediaFile.Status == 'Missing', EventMediaFile.Status == 'Failed')).where(
            EventMediaFile.RetryCount < 3)
```

but getting this error even though I have placed the code inside the app.app_context()

```
'Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.'
```

Please help out here, any leads would be appreciated..!!

I just need to fetch all the columns of all the rows based on the condition..!! thats it..!!

Comment: What is the output of `print(result)` after you execute the query?  Please [edit] the question to include it.

Comment: I have edited the question with the response as well please have a look @snakecharmerb

Comment: same response bro @python_user which I mentioned in the question i.e. just the primary key values and no other columns..!!

Comment: That looks like it might be the `repr` of the object to me, which is what I would expect to see.  `session.execute` would return a iterable of tuples, where each tuple contains a single instance of the model class.

Answer (score 2):

The output that you have reported from the console is the default string representation of the model object, which outputs only the primary keys. You can still access other properties of the object through the DOT notation as attributes.
For example,

```
print(obj.URL)
print(obj.width)
```

To override this behavior and have a custom representation of the object, you will have to implement the `__repr__` method in the model class.